# "Template has freeform signer(s)." Docusign

Tags: flutter, docusignapi

I am facing issue while using docusign in flutter it gives me error
"Template has freeform signer(s)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you are not providing tabs for some recipients.
Now, normally, that is ok, it will result in "freeform signing" where the recipients can drag and drop their own signing elements.
However, certain plans and certain accounts do not allow this because of legal restrictions (for example in the healthcare industry).
So, I don't have your code here, but you have to ensure you added tabs (signing elements) for all your recipients.

Comment: Yes i added sign field in document which i added in template and after that it works fine